# Unable to send web push notification on iOS, works perfectly fine on Android devices

Tags: javascript, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, service-worker, web-push

I am using service worker concept (API) to send web push notifications, [this](https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/progressive-web-apps/9781617294587/) is the book that I followed and got the code sample from. Below code works perfectly fine to get the subscription from a client and I am able to send notifications successfully on Chrome android devices

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js').then(function (registration){
    return registration.pushManager.getSubscription().then(function (subscription){
    })
}).catch()
...
```

The exact code doesn't seem to work on iPhone chrome web browser. I tried to add some `console.log`s to see what's happening and it looks like the `registration` object that we  got from above code doesn't have `pushManager` property set and because of that below is the problem that I see in iPhone chrome console logs.

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'registration.pushManager.getsubscription')
```

Here is the code that adds those console logs

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js').then(function (registration){
            if (registration){
                console.log("registration is found " , registration)
            } else {
                console.log("registration is not found")
            }

            if (registration.pushManager){
                console.log("pushmanager was found on registration and calling getSubscription() ", registration.pushManager.getSubscription())
            } else{
                console.log("pushmanager was not found on registration")
            }
...
...
```

and the output of this code, on iPhone chrome browser is attached here.

I was wondering if I should [Notification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification) API instead, but was not able to figure out if I can get subscription details using Notification API.

I wanted to see if someone already got into this problem and was able to resolve that.

[image]

The other thing that I was able to figure out was

```
'PushManager' in window
```

returns `false` in the envs where notifications are not working (iOS chrome).